# how to add a new row on click of enter in Kendo UI Grid

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid

I am looking for some help in Kendo UI Grid, I have a grid with Add new record, cancel changes buttons. when I click on Add new record button I am getting a new line, I want to implement the same functionality on click of enter in the keyboard.
here is my sample:

```
<div  id="tstCnfgnMsrGridDiv">
    <div data-role="grid" data-scrollable="true" data-editable="inline" data-resizable="true"
            data-toolbar="['create', 'cancel']"
            data-columns="[
                             { field: 'name'            , title: 'Name', width: 150},
                             { field: 'descr'       , title: 'Description', width: 150},
                             { field: 'createdDate'     , title: 'Created On', type : 'date', 'format' : '{0: MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss}', 'width' : 100},
                             { field: 'createdByName'   , title: 'Created By', width: 100 },
                             { field: 'modifiedDate'    , title: 'Modified On', type : 'date', 'format' : '{0: MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss}', 'width' : 100}
                             { field: 'modifiedByName'  , title: 'Modified By', width: 100},


                         ]"
            data-bind="source: empDataSource, events : {edit : editGrid}"
            data-scrollable='true' 
            data-sortable='true' 
            data-filterable='true'
            data-pageable="{ 
                             pageSize: 15,
                             pageSizes: [15, 50, 100, 200, 500],
                             refresh : true,                                                         
                             buttonCount : 5
                             }"
            style="width: 100%; height: 650px">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="tstCnfgnMsrGridSubDiv"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../resources/js/coreCnfgn/measure.js"></script>
<script>



   $(document).ready(function() {
       var tooltip = $("#tstCnfgnMsrGridDiv").kendoTooltip({
           filter: "th",
           width: 120,
           position: "bottom"
       }).data("kendoTooltip");

       $("#tstCnfgnMsrGridDiv").find("th").click(false);

       **$(document.body).keydown(function(e) {
           if (e.altKey && e.keyCode == 13) {

               $("#tstCnfgnMsrGridDiv").addRow();
           }
       });**
   });
</script>
```

when i checked `kendo.all.min.js` for Create - `create:{text:"Add new record",imageClass:"k-add",className:"k-grid-add",iconClass:"k-icon"}`

`k-grid-add` class has addRow method, I tried calling the same method in my html page, but it is not working.

Can someone please help me with this.

Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Sadly because kendo grid takes over the ENTER even on any child of the table I couldn't register an event to do the logic.

if you look at kendo.all and search

```
case keys.ENTER:
                        e.preventDefault();
                        if (isCell) {
                            if (that.options.editable && that.options.editable.update !== false) {
                                that._cachedCurrent = that.current;
                                that.list._startEditHandler(that.current);
                                $(this).one('keyup', function (e) {
                                    e.stopPropagation();
                                });
                            }
                        } else {
                            that.current.children('a.k-link').click();
                        }
                        break;
```

You can always change that source if you wish but I personally would not.

Comment: No, David. on click of enter i need to create blank new row , right now  Add new row button is adding new blank row , and the same functionality needs to happend when i click on the enter button.